# Formula required to compare two columns and give the result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to excel formulas please help me here. I have two columns U and Z column where in U column contains values like Exceptional, High, Moderate, Low and Z Column contains the values like Unlikely, Possible, Likely, Certain.

My question is I have to get the answer in AA column as Critical, major, Limited based on comparing the two columns U and Z Column. Conditions below.

- U column contains Exceptional and Z column contains Unlikely then in AA column I should get the answer as Critical.
- U column contains Exceptional and Z column contains Possible then in AA column I should get the answer as Critical.
- U column contains Exceptional and Z column contains likely then in AA column I should get the answer as Critical.
- U column contains Exceptional and Z column contains Certain then in AA column I should get the answer as Critical.
- U column contains High and Z column contains Unlikely then in AA column I should get the answer as Major.
- U column contains High and Z column contains Possible then in AA column I should get the answer as Major.
- U column contains High and Z column contains Likely then in AA column I should get the answer as Critical.
- U column contains High and Z column contains Certain then in AA column I should get the answer as Critical.
- U column contains Moderate and Z column contains Unlikely then in AA column I should get the answer as Limited.
- U column contains Moderate and Z column contains Possible then in AA column I should get the answer as Major.
- U column contains Moderate and Z column contains Likely then in AA column I should get the answer as Major.
- U column contains Moderate and Z column contains Certain then in AA column I should get the answer as Major.
- U column contains Low and Z column contains Unlikely then in AA column I should get the answer as Limited.
- U column contains Low and Z column contains Possible then in AA column I should get the answer as Limited.
- U column contains Low and Z column contains Likely then in AA column I should get the answer as Limited.
- U column contains Low and Z column contains Certain then in AA column I should get the answer as Limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these instances it's handy to create some helper lists containing the possible text string to make references easy on you.

[image]

The formula I sued in `AA1` translates to:

```
=IF(AND(U1=$AC$1,SUMPRODUCT(--(Z1=$AD$1:$AD$4))>0),$AE$1,IF(AND(U1=$AC$2,SUMPRODUCT(--(Z1=$AD$1:$AD$2))>0),$AE$2,IF(AND(U1=$AC$2,SUMPRODUCT(--(Z1=$AD$3:$AD$4))>0),$AE$1,IF(AND(U1=$AC$3,Z1=$AD$1),$AE$3,IF(AND(U1=$AC$3,SUMPRODUCT(--(Z1=$AD$2:$AD$4))>0),$AE$2,IF(AND(U1=$AC$4,SUMPRODUCT(--(Z1=$AD$1:$AD$4))>0),$AE$3,))))))
```

Drag down...

Comment: You are great and you saved my life. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution. Formula is for cell AA1, assuming your data starts at row 1:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(3*MATCH(U1,{"Low","Moderate","High","Exceptional"},0)
+MATCH(V1,{"Unlikely","Possible","Likely","Certain"},0),{0,8,12,100},1),"Limited","Major","Critical")
```

How it works:

> Low=3 points
>   Moderate=6 points
>   High=9 points
>   Exceptional=12 points
>   Unlikely=1 point
>   Possible=2 points
>   Likely=3 points
>   Certain=3 points

Summing:

> 0-7: Limited
>    8-11: Major
>   12+ : Critical

Comment: Very creative, was thinking about `CHOOSE()`. I like this :)

Comment: Yes, I answered this in a kind of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com way ;)

Comment: Working fine now, Thanks